# CMake with Qt3d for Qt5?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, qt3d

I have installed Qt5 and Qt3d from the ubuntu-developers repository (I'm under Ubuntu 13.04) and I would like to compile a very simple application with CMake (my version is 2.8.10.1). A working CMakeLists.txt for a Qt helloworld is the following :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)

project(testproject)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(helloworld helloworld.cpp)

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
qt5_use_modules(helloworld Widgets)
```

But what would be the CMakeLists.txt of a basic Qt3d program like this example :
https://gitorious.org/wiki-sources/wiki-sources/trees/master/qt3d/glview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt3d is a regular Qt module, just like Qt Widgets. So you should add Qt3d to your project just as you do it for Widgets:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project(testproject)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt53D)
add_executable(helloworld teapotview.cpp main.cpp)
qt5_use_modules(helloworld Widgets 3D)
```

I've tested this CMakeLists.txt with Teapot example. It's available [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt3d/trees/master/examples/qt3d/teapot). Note that the example you've posted was written for Qt4 and will not work with Qt5.

I've used Ubuntu 13.04 with `qt3d5-dev` package available in the main repository.

Comment: `Qt53D` seems to want profile suffixes, for example `Qt53DCore` instead of `Qt53D`

Comment: Im getting ```CMakeLists.txt:46: error: By not providing "FindQt53D.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt53D", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt53D" with any of the following names: Qt53DConfig.cmake qt53d-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "Qt53D" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt53D_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt53D" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.```

Comment: ```find_package(Qt53D)``` fails for me